# CSS dropdown menu with vertical

Tags: css

I have this code to add a menu... it works fine, but I need now a submenu/dropdown menu

```
.fancyNav {
    /* Affects the UL element */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 999;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fancyNav li {
    /* Specifying a fallback color and we define CSS3 gradients for the major browsers: */
    background: #CCC;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=10);
    opacity: .7;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        /* Adding a 1px inset highlight for a more polished efect: */
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.fancyNav li:after {
        /* This creates a pseudo element inslide each LI */
    content: '.';
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
        /* Gradients! */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(168,168,168,0)), to(rgba(168,168,168,0.5)));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%, rgba(255,255,255,1));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(168,168,168,0.5), rgba(168,168,168,0) 50%, rgba(168,168,168,0.5));
        /* Creating borders with box-shadow. Useful, as they don't affect the size of the element. */
        box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff,1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        /* This will create a smooth transition for the opacity property */
        -moz-transition:0.25s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.25s all;
    -o-transition:0.25s all;
    transition:0.25s all;}
    /* Treating the first LI and li:after elements separately */
    .fancyNav li:first-child:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:first-child:after{
    box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,2px 0 0 #fff;
        }
    .fancyNav li:last-child{
    }
    /* Treating the last LI and li:after elements separately */
    .fancyNav li:last-child:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:last-child:after{
    box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0 0 #a3a3a3,-2px 0 0 #fff;
        }
    .fancyNav li:hover:after,
    .fancyNav li.selected:after,
    .fancyNav li:target:after{
    /* This property triggers the CSS3 transition */
    opacity:1;
        }
    .fancyNav:hover li.selected:after,
    .fancyNav:hover li:target:after{
    /* Hides the targeted li when we are hovering on the UL */
    opacity:0;
        }
    .fancyNav li.selected:hover:after,
    .fancyNav li:target:hover:after{
    opacity:1 !important;
        }
    /* Styling the anchor elements */
    .menudiv{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    width:951px;
    margin-left:-476px;
    left:50%;
    }
    .menlog{
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;

    }
    .menlog2{
    padding:12px 15px 15px;

    }
    .corrente{
       background-color:white;
    padding:12px 15px 15px;
    }
    .fancyNav li a{
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    white-space:nowrap;
        }
    .fancyNav a.homeIcon{
    background:url('../img/home.png') no-repeat center center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    nav{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

    }
    a, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    color:#54a6de;
    }
    a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    }

   <nav>
```

I need now a submenu dropdownmenu with menu style how can i add a simple dropdown item, with same style that the menu?

Html code,

```
<nav><ul class="fancyNav">
<li id="quemsomos" class="menlog"><a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/Logo.png"  width="37" height="45" /></a></li>
<li id="quemsomos"><a href="quemsomos.php?web=1"><font face="din" size="4">QUEM SOMOS</font></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some HTML? Without it, the CSS is rather useless.

Comment: Post your html code or fiddle it.

Comment: I add the html code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some code, I hope this help you:

add these classes to your CSS:

```
ul ul li{
    float:none !important;
}
ul ul{
    padding:0;
    display:none;
    position:relative;    /* updated */
    z-index:2;            /* updated */
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

and add your sub menu like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="fancyNav">
    <li id="quemsomos" class="menlog"><a href="index.php"><img src="imgs/Logo.png"  width="37" height="45" /></a></li>
    <li id="quemsomos"><a href="quemsomos.php?web=1"><font face="din" size="4">QUEM SOMOS</font></a>

    <!--start of sub menu-->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test DropDown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test DropDown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test DropDown</a></li>
      </ul>
    <!--end of sub menu-->

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/HJADv/1/)

Comment: @Ricardo: update `ul ul` class like answer. you need to set `position` and `z-index` `:)`

Comment: Thanks, now two problems... first i need remove the border in submenu, and the other problem is when you do mouseover ok, but when you do mouse out you see something show and disapears automatic... i only need when you do mouseover change to white nothing more... thanks once again

Comment: Thanks... the only thing i can´t resolve is the mouse over show something i dont understand...